# How can i make query and sort in mongodb $near and sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new with mongodb, and i'm having a weird problem with my sort and query.

Right now i'm using **paginate (mongoose-paginate)** a plugin for mongoose

This is kind of my collection

```
One: { 
level: Number,
random:[Number]
}
```

So the problem is that the sort is messing with my query, **when i comment the sort the result is more or less right** my random is making right but also want the level sort but is always making the sort more important that the search.

is impossible? some help please.

My code is:

```
const config = {

            select: 'level random',
            page:parseInt(page),
            limit: parseInt(perPage),
            sort: '-level'
        };
await One.paginate({ $near : [Math.random(), 0] },config);
```

**& the result with math.random= 0.2, and -level**

```
{
level:2, random:[0.7268446184677886,0],
level:2, random:[0.301999760447198,0],
level:1, random:[0.3970620502264359,0],

}
```

**with math.random= 0.2, and NO -level** This is woring perfect with the random, but i also want the level sort

**incorrect***

```
{

level:2, random:[0.301999760447198,0],
level:1, random:[0.3970620502264359,0],
level:2, random:[0.7268446184677886,0],

}
```

**correct***

```
{

level:2, random:[0.301999760447198,0],
level:2, random:[0.7268446184677886,0],
level:1, random:[0.3970620502264359,0],


}
```

** what i want with random= 0.2 & -level**

```
{

level:2, random:[0.301999760447198,0],
level:2, random:[0.7268446184677886,0],
level:1, random:[0.3970620502264359,0],

}
```

** what i want with random= 0.8 & -level**

```
{
level:2, random:[0.7268446184677886,0],
level:2, random:[0.301999760447198,0],
level:1, random:[0.3970620502264359,0],

}
```